# Laravel 5.1 - How to get not attached pivot registers for add

Tags: php, database, laravel-5.1

I am doing a CRUD with Laravel 5.1. When I click the add button, a form with a select box Is shown (the controller sends all the data correctly). All works fine, but I want to improve the form not showing elements attached to the model.

Example: 2 models, User and Role, with a Relationship Many to Many. My controller gets all the roles attached to the current user EXCEPT which are already attached.

Any idea how to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can get the roles `ids` attached with the current `User` :

```
 $user_roles = Auth::user()->roles()->lists('id')->toArray();
```

Then get all the roles exept the `$user_roles` :

```
 $other_roles = Roles::whereNotIn('id', $user_roles);
```

And finally attach those roles to the `User` :

```
foreach($other_roles as $role){
    Auth::user()->roles()->attach($role->id);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know about whereNotIn function, but is logic it exists. Thanks a lot!